# How to pass values of alert query ending with double quotes to ARM template parameter file

Tags: json, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-rm-template

I Am using Azure pipelines to automate the Log query based alerts. I am passing runtime parameter values to Azure variable first and then replacing the parameter.json file by the query by using the replacing token task in the pipeline.  When I am passing the queries which are not ending with double quotes", the ResourceGroup deployment task getting succeeded. But when I am passing a query which is ending already with Double quotes getting failed.

Eg:

This is my base query.

```
"ApiManagementGatewayLogs
| where ApiId == ""my-api""
| where ResponseCode == 429
| where _SubscriptionId==""xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"""
```

since my runtime parameter is type of "string", passing this as single line  as below

```
ApiManagementGatewayLogs| where ApiId == ""my-api""| where ResponseCode == 429| where _SubscriptionId==""xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""
```

But the deployments getting failed with below error

```
Template deployment validation was completed successfully.
Starting Deployment.
Deployment name is digitalAlerts
There were errors in your deployment. Error code: DeploymentFailed.
##[error]At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.
##[error]Details:
##[error]BadRequest: {
  "error": {
    "message": "The request had some invalid properties",
    "code": "BadArgumentError",
    "correlationId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "innererror": {
      "code": "SyntaxError",
      "message": "Request is invalid and cannot be processed: Syntax error: SYN0001: I could not parse that, sorry. [line:position=0:0]. Query: 'let ['ApiManagementGatewayLogs'] = view () { datatable(['TenantId']:string,['TimeGenerated']:datetime,['OperationName']:string,['CorrelationId']:string,['Region']:string,['IsRequestSuccess']:bool,['Category']:string,['TotalTime']:long,['CallerIpAddress']:string,['Method']:string,['Url']:string,['ClientProtocol']:string,['ResponseCode']:int,['BackendMethod']:string,['BackendUrl']:string,['BackendResponseCode']:int,['BackendProtocol']:string,['RequestSize']:int,['ResponseSize']:int,['Cache']:string,['CacheTime']:long,['BackendTime']:long,['ClientTime']:long,['ApiId']:string,['OperationId']:string,['ProductId']:string,['UserId']:string,['ApimSubscriptionId']:string,['BackendId']:string,['LastErrorElapsed']:long,['LastErrorSource']:string,['LastErrorScope']:string,['LastErrorSection']:string,['LastErrorReason']:string,['LastErrorMessage']:string,['ApiRevision']:string,['ClientTlsVersion']:string,['RequestHeaders']:dynamic,['ResponseHeaders']:dynamic,['BackendRequestHeaders']:dynamic,['BackendResponseHeaders']:dynamic,['RequestBody']:string,['ResponseBody']:string,['BackendRequestBody']:string,['BackendResponseBody']:string,['Errors']:dynamic,['TraceRecords']:dynamic,['SourceSystem']:string,['Type']:string,['_ResourceId']:string,['_SubscriptionId']:string)[] };restrict access to (*);\r\nApiManagementGatewayLogs\\n| where ApiId == \\\"my-api\\\"\\n| where ResponseCode == 429\\n| where _SubscriptionId==\\\"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\\"\\n\\n'"
    }
  }
}
##[error]Check out the troubleshooting guide to see if your issue is addressed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-resource-group-deployment?view=azure-devops#troubleshooting
##[error]Task failed while creating or updating the template deployment.
```

Looking for 2 solutions:

- From Pipeline side How Can I pass the queries in the same format as my Base query where users can easily pass their queries , which will replace my parameters.json in proper format
- Secondly, how can avoid the above issue by passing the queries with double quotes ending.

Note already tried by modifying the query by replacing the " with / but didn't resolve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not completely clear from the question but it sounds like you're deploying something like a [scheduled query rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.insights/scheduledqueryrules?tabs=json) using an ARM template via an Azure DevOps pipeline.

As the ARM template is a json document any strings will need to be wrapped in double quotes.  However the log query you are passing into is written in Kusto and as per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/string) strings in Kusto queries can be wrapped in single or double quotes.

If you rewrite your query as:

`ApiManagementGatewayLogs | where ApiId == 'my-api'| where ResponseCode == 429 | where _SubscriptionId=='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'`

it should succeed.  In your parameters.json file this would look something like:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "logQuery": {
            "value": "ApiManagementGatewayLogs | where ApiId == 'my-api'| where ResponseCode == 429 | where _SubscriptionId=='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'"
        }
     }
}
```